# how would i rewrite a file to a subdomain in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, url-rewriting

I have a subdirectory for various cities.How can I use htaccess to rewrite these to a subdomain?

for example
http://www.domain.com/search/atlanta.php

to

http://www.atlanta.domain.com

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use htaccess for this. htaccess is used to reduce permissions within a folder. You have to define a sub-domain on the dns what is providing the domain. In the Apache configuration you add another virtual host to host the domain atlanta.domain.com.

Comment: i have set up a wild card dns for my domain.  I thought that i could use htaccess to rewrite the path to a subdomain.  maybe not. Thanks for your input, i'll keep looking around